# Java Testing in Eclipse, writing methods

Tags: java, junit

I'm having trouble writing test methods in Eclipse, I have created a JUnit Case class, selected the class and methods I'd like to test. Now I'm faced with a class with empty methods. I'm not actually sure what to in the methods. I've read you need to create a new instance of the class I want to test them call it's method. I've looked online but nothing is making sense. This is part of the class I want to test:

```
public class FilmSystem {


private String filmName;
private String lecture;
private String ageRating;
private String ticketCost;
private int noOfSeats;

public FilmSystem(String film, String lect, String age, String price, int seats){
    filmName = film;
    lecture = lect;
    ageRating = age;
    ticketCost = price;
    noOfSeats = seats;


}

public String getFilmName(){
    return filmName;
}
```

How would I test the getFilmName method? 
Thanks.

Comment: Instantiate an object of type `FilmSystem` and call the method on it. `FilmSystem filmSystem = new FilmSystem("film", "lect","age","price", 4); filmSystem.getFilmName();`

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it answered your question? Or let me know how it didn't so I can adapt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick example:

```
public class FilmSystem{

    private String filmName;
    private String lecture;
    private String ageRating;
    private String ticketCost;
    private int noOfSeats;

    public FilmSystem(String film, String lect, String age, 
                      String price, int seats){
        filmName = film;
        lecture = lect;
        ageRating = age;
        ticketCost = price;
        noOfSeats = seats;

    }

    public String getFilmName(){
        return filmName;
        }

}

public class FilmSystemTest{

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnCorrectName(){
        FilmSystem filmSystem = new FilmSystem("Ocean's Eleven", "", "", "", 0);

        Assert.assertEquals("Ocean's Eleven", filmSystem.getFilmName());
    }
}
```

Although I have to say. Testing a *getter* doesn't seem quite so interesting

Comment: That worked, I understand what I need to do now. I was on the right lines before but I wasn't doing things in the right places. And yeah it's not interesting but it's a requirement, so I'm just jumping through the hoops. Cheers guys.

Comment: I would put "Ocean's Eleven" in a field or variable so the test doesn't fail (or succeed) due to a typo. What if there was a bug in the class that deleted posessives ('s) and you accidentally typed "Ocean Eleven" in the assert? Avoid the typo problem.

Comment: Secondly, always put a message on the assert. It seems like a pain when you are doing it. When one failure shows up in a few months or years and you can't remember what you were testing, that 1st parameter message comes in handy. Better than a comment.

Comment: don't you have to assing "Ocean's Eleven" to the field or variable anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Your unit test should not differ from the canonical use of your object in that context.  Since `FilmSystem` is immutable (that is, none of those fields have setters), you will have to assert that what you instantiate your object with is what your object returns.

```
@Test
public void testFilmName() {
    // arrange
    FilmSystem fs = new FilmSystem("Some movie", "", "", "", 10);
    // act
    // no actions
    // assert
    assertEquals("Some movie", fs.getFilmName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unit Testing philosophy is AAA: Arrange, Act and Assert

You probably won't need tests for a class like that one, but here is the general idea.

```
public class TestFilmSystem {

    @Test
    public void test_get_film_name(){
        /*
         * Arrange
         */         
        String expectedFilmName = "Hobbit- An unexpected journey";
        FilmSystem fs = new FilmSystem(expectedFilmName, "xpto", "12", "12.99€", 100);      
        /*
         * Act
         */

        String resultFilmName = fs.getFilmName();           
        /*
         * Assert
         */         
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedFilmName,resultFilmName);           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fill in the rest (or let Eclipse do it). I'm just being lazy.

```
private static final String FILM = "Casa Blanca";
.. similar for all ...

@Test
public void testFilmName() {

  FilmSystem f = new FilmSystem(FILM, LECTURE, AGE_RATING, PRICE, SEAT_COUNT);
  assertEquals("File name is wrong", FILM, f.getFilmName());

}
```